# Is there any alternative for state in class component of react native?

Tags: datepicker, multiple-date-picker

i have a dynamic form that contains multiple date fields. i don't know how many date fields will be there in future.  if i select one date from date picker it shows in all fields the same date as shown in the picture.

i don't want to use state because i don't know the exact number of date fields in my form in future as it is dynamic. is there any alternative for state or any solution for it with state?

in the given picture i used state just to show the issue, now i want to use something by which can get date from multiple fields

like this here second field picked the same date of first field

[image]

```
if (item.element == "DatePicker") {
                let i_id = item.id;

                return (
                     <View style={styles.input}>
                     <View style={styles.layout}>
                     <Text>{item.label}</Text>
                    <Text>{this.state.cdate}</Text>
                  <Button title="Date" onPress={showDatePicker} />
                    <DateTimePickerModal
                         isVisible={this.state.setDatePickerVisibility}
                         mode="date"
                         onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                         onCancel={hideDatePicker}
                    />
                   </View>
                 </View>
          
                     );
                   }
```

const showDatePicker = () => {
this.setState({
setDatePickerVisibility: true,
});
};

```
const hideDatePicker = () => {
  this.setState({
    setDatePickerVisibility: false,
  });
};

const handleConfirm = (date) => {
  Moment.locale('en');
let dates =   Moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')

  this.setState({
    cdate: dates,});
  hideDatePicker();
};
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, copy the text into your question and use the code format button

Comment: sorry! removed that pictures now we have question in code format